# How can I keep the cheese from leaking out of my cordon bleu during cooking?

Tags: chicken, frying, chicken-breast, french-cuisine

I use flour to coat, including the ends, and I use toothpicks to hold the wider part shut.  Even when I try to fold the cutlet envelope style, most of my cheese melts out. I cook them on the stove top with butter.

Is there another technique that would prevent that?

P.S. I use Swiss cheese.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most common reason for leakage with Cordon Bleu Chicken is that the packets are too thick, which makes it impossible to get a perfect fold; you need to pound the breasts *very* thin - less than 1/2", maybe a little more than 1/4".

The other "trick" is to make a small cut along the folded edge of the breast after you fold and seal the packets, which essentially makes it almost like a sandwich; the top and bottom parts can move independently and you don't have tension trying to pull the top piece away.

Just don't cut so deep that you cause an *immediate* leak; if you've pounded the breast to 1/3" thickness, then your cut should be no more than about 1/8".

If you do it this way, you shouldn't even need to use toothpicks; I never do, and I haven't sprung a single leak in my last 20 or so preparations.

Comment: Note: By "top" and "bottom" I am referring to the sides with and without the seam, respectively.  Generally you'd start cooking them "upside down."

Answer (score 3):

I have heard that it is good to freeze/chill the cheese before inserting it into the chicken.  That way, it takes longer to liquify and leak out.  The chicken will cook around it (heat moves from outside in), and by the time the chicken is almost done, the cheese is just getting melty and wonderful.

YMMV